# How can I get a subtotal count for rows in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I have this SQL Query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHRASE WHERE JLPT = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHRASE WHERE JLPT = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHRASE WHERE JLPT = 3
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHRASE WHERE JLPT = 4
```

Is there a way I could combine these queries into 1 so as to give me a count of how many JLPT rows have a value of 1,2,3 & 4 ?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Expected result for a sample data would be good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT JLPT,
       COUNT(*)
FROM PHRASE
WHERE JLPT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY JLPT;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use condition aggregation if you want these values in one row.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN JLPT = 1 THEN 1 END) JLPT1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN JLPT = 2 THEN 1 END) JLPT2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN JLPT = 3 THEN 1 END) JLPT3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN JLPT = 4 THEN 1 END) JLPT4
FROM PHRASE
```